# Mongoose ValidationError upon creating new user in Passport KeystoneJS

Tags: node.js, oauth, mongoose, passport.js, keystonejs

I'm using the [Passport authentication plugin for KeystoneJS](https://github.com/JohnnyEstilles/keystone-social-login) in my project.

Everything works great if the user account exists and is tied to the social network being used. When creating a new user, though, with the config option `'auto create user': true`, I end up with a 500 error on the oauth callback route. The log says it's a validation error.

```
ValidationError: Validation failed 
  at model.Document.invalidate (/app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1021:32) 
  at /app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:970:16 
  at validate (/app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:610:7) 
  at /app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:627:9 
  at Array.forEach (native) 
  at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:614:19) 
  at /app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:968:9 
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

What could be causing this?

---

**Edit**

User model:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
Types = keystone.Field.Types,
social = require('keystone-social-login');

/**
 * User Model
 * ==========
 */

var User = new keystone.List('User');

User.add({
    name: { type: Types.Name, required: true, index: true },
    email: { type: Types.Email, initial: true, required: true, index: true },
    password: { type: Types.Password, initial: true, required: true }
}, 'Permissions', {
    userLevel: { type: Types.Select, options: 'user, business, admin', default: 'user', initial: true }
});

// Provide access to Keystone
User.schema.virtual('canAccessKeystone').get(function() {
    return this.userLevel === 'admin';
});


/**
 * Registration
 */

social.plugin(User);

User.defaultColumns = 'name, email, userLevel';
User.register();
```

Comment: It means that [Mongoose validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) have failed on some field. Try printing [`errors` property of your `ValidationError` object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-invalidate) to find out what's wrong with your user.

Comment: Any console.log added to the plugin is ignored. I just get the same 500 error page and the same console errors. I don't see how I can output the errors from the object.

Comment: Can you show the code of your user model?

Comment: Thanks. It look all right. So as @LeonidBeschastny said, we need to be able to see `errors` property of `ValidationError` object. Could you add `console.log(err.errors)` inside 500 error handler in the router file (normally `routes/index.js`), like this: `keystone.set('500', function(err, req, res, next) {
        (...)
        console.log(err.errors)
        res.err(err, title, message);
    });`

Comment: @lukaszfiszer You, sir, are a godsend! `ValidatorError: Path 'password' is required.` -- I had no idea how to access this error before. Thank you!

Comment: That looks like a bug in keystone-social-login module, because it makes not sense to require `password` field when user authenticates via an external provider. Removing `required: true` from password field should help. I recommend doing the same for `email` if you want to use Twitter authentication, as twitter does not give access to users' email via their oAuth.

Comment: Good point. Thank you again. I will make those changes and cross my fingers :)

Comment: This error frequently appears when you put something on an Enum and then a default value that doesn't  belong to the enum list.